# VS2012 WebAPI: No type was found that matches the controller named 'CpbOutcome'

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

Can somebody help with this? I have this controller:

```
public class CbpOutcomeController : ApiController
{
    // POST /api/CbpOutcome/1/ 
    public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateCbpOutcome(CbpOutcome co)
    {
        ... snip ...
        return resp_msg;
    }
}
```

And this route:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "HubProfilePostRoute", // Route name
            "hub/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ProfileByRegionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Region/{region_name}"
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ProfileByGlobalPriorityApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GlobalPriority/{priority_name}"
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And when I make the `POST` to `http://localhost:2515/api/CpbOutcome`, with this JSON structure:

```
{ "Id":0, "Description":"This is a description", "DisplayOrder": 3, 
  "ModifiedBy":"Somebody's name here", "Cbp": { "Id": 163 }}
```

I get this message:

```
No type was found that matches the controller named 'CpbOutcome'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---**Edit**---

See the spelling of the your API class.

```
public class CbpOutcomeController : ApiController
```

Then see the spelling of your URL:

```
http://localhost:2515/api/CpbOutcome
```

Notice the Cbp and the Cpb

---**End Edit**---

API Controller URL should reside inside the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

Not inside the `RouteConfig.cs` file

Analyse the default template provide with VS2012 for a Web API project and you will see it.

Comment: Steven, I have already 30 WebAPI controllers and they all work fine from RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Typical Problem-Exists-Between-Keyboard-And-Chair Error??

Comment: I am trying to but I have to wait 3 more minutes.

Comment: ANOTHER CAUSE: there is another way to get this error w o a typo:

Comment: ANOTHER CAUSE: there is another way to get this error w o a typo: 1.) r-click the Controllers dir/ Add new controller 2.) for template, select (Web) API controller with read/write actions, using Entity Framework. 3.) in Controller name box enter a name that DOES NOT end in the word Controller. (I used wsController_1)  4.) use the urls that should work.  <br><br> The generated comments in the class said this would work api/wsController_1  Once I changed the class name to wsController  This worked  api/ws   (definite bug.)